# why does RedirectToAction("Index") in HomeController, go to "/" instead of "/Home/Index"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

Program.cs contains the following (put there by the default project template):

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

HomeController.cs contains:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");   // goes to "/"
        //return RedirectToAction("About"); // goes to "/Home/About"
    }
```

return RedirectToAction("Index"), causes `/` to load instead of `/Home/Index`. Can anyone explain?

I'm unable to understand why this would happen, according to the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0

**EDIT:**

Technically I have a Blazor `Index.razor` page at `/`, that loads instead of my `Index.cshtml` view at /Home/Index. So i'm really seeing a different page.

Comment: The index at `RedirectToAction("Index")` is an Action, not a url. goes to Index action in the same controller.

Comment: @OkanKaradag but `/Index` is not in the `Home` controller

Comment: @LeiYang i'm not sure what you mean. it's not going to `/Home/Index`

Comment: *I'm unable to understand why this would happen* -- can you tell us what you expect to happen?

Comment: @LeiYang I expect `/Home/Index` to load when i `return RedirectToAction("Index")` in an action in HomeController.cs

Comment: i think this is business logic. for example, when you go shopping, you add some goods to  cart, now you're in cartcontroller, then login is required, after login you want redirect back to cart, not home page.

Comment: @symbiont if action have no in same controller, default controller runs

Comment: @symbiont What does your `Index` action method look like?

Comment: @RahulSharma i've added it

Comment: @symbiont the question's body and title are now out of sync after the last edit.

Comment: @Julian oops. it's fixed now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the following:

`RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`

According to the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#:%7E:text=NET%20MVC%205.2-,RedirectToAction(String%2C%20String),-Redirects%20to%20the).

Starting [here on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/main/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs), it looks like it just builds a URL based on the provided values. So omitting the controller name, the route will not be fully built. Since this is a string based constructor, the method does not know what you are actually targeting.

Comment: why don't i have to do that for other actions like "About"? a problem with looking at the internal .NET code, is the assumption that it's correct

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, and I admit I am having a hard time finding the official documentation for it that says it this plainly, is that this is filling in defaults:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

What it is saying is that if there is no controller or action, use HomeController as the controller and index as the action. If Id is included, just add it as a parameter to the previous controller and action listed.

Comment: thanks for actually trying to answer my question